# Separate objects can't be selected individually

Tags: add-on, edit-mode, workflow, parent

I created an robot arm that has multiple parented objects in it. After that I selected all individual objects (in object mode) and duplicated them with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Everything worked normally.

But now after I saved and reopened the file every time I select certain objects from one of the arms the other equivalent objects from the other arms will also be selected. Like in the image where it will select all base pieces even though I only selected one of them. How can I separate these objects again ?

I used Blender 2.90.0 if that is any help.

[image: Issue]

Comment: Please check to determine if these objects share a common base mesh.  This is possible in Blender.  Some people choose to use this feature.  User preferences determines what is shared at the time of duplication.  User counts on data can tell you the user count.  Materials can be shared.   Base Meshes can be shared.  You can search this site for a tutorial on duplication and how user preferences controls the denouement.

Comment: Thanks for your response I checked but it seems all objects have different meshes.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. It was the KIT OPS add-on every time you would copy an insert and reload the Blender file (save and reopen) the objects would be linked like that but selecting the effected inserts and pressing the "Remove KIT OPS props" button in the KIT OPS tab will fix it.